# How can I create dynamic widget in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, widget

I want to create dynamic widget in wordpress , Please help to get this done in standard and easy way. I have read below post but did not satisfied :

[Dynamic WordPress Widget Creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338830/dynamic-wordpress-widget-creation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you will need to register your sidebar or widget ready area for your theme. You can register multiple sidebars and widget ready areas. Copy and paste this code in your theme’s functions.php file`

```
function wpb_widgets_init() {

register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'wpb' ),
    'id' => 'sidebar-1',
    'description' => __( 'The main sidebar appears on the right on each page except the front page template', 'wpb' ),
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</aside>',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );

register_sidebar( array(
    'name' =>__( 'Front page sidebar', 'wpb'),
    'id' => 'sidebar-2',
    'description' => __( 'Appears on the static front page template', 'wpb' ),
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</aside>',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpb_widgets_init' );
```

`
In above code, we have registered two sidebars. We set them names and descriptions to identify them on Widgets screen. The description parameter can be used to tell users where this sidebar appears in the theme. The wpb is the name of the theme we are working on, it is used here to make these strings translatable. You should replace it with your theme name.

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) : ?>
<div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
</div>
```

In this example code, we have used sidebar id to call the sidebar we want to display here. Change the sidebar id to display another sidebar. For example, you can register three sidebars for footer area and then call them one by one in your theme’s footer.php template.